# How I can use callback in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, listener

I have View and one CircleShape , which should show toast in this View. And I use it in main Activity.
This is my interface

```
interface OnClickListenerInterface {
  fun onClick()
}
```

It is CircleShape( it is View in my xml) and listener in my View. I want to implement OnClick in my Activity.

```
 var listener: OnClickListenerInterface? = null

 mCircleShape.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
      if (listener == null) return@OnClickListener
      listener!!.onClick()
    })
```

I know , that in Kotlin getters and setters generic automatics, but how I can set listener if it private. It is code from my Activity, but It doesn't work

```
CircleShape.listener  = object :OnClickListenerInterface{
      override fun onClick() {
        ToastUtils.showSuccessMessage(getContext(),"pressed")
      }
    }
```

How I should to use Callback, onClickListenere in Kotlin?

Comment: "It doesn't work" - what's the error?

Comment: Listener isn't active

Comment: Helped me in implementing a callback. The `object:OnClickListenerInterface` part was not known to me. Thanks

Comment: Here are some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608847/753632

Answer (score 104):

A more simpler solution by using lambda.

Inside `CircleShape.kt`, declare a lambda function.

```
var listener: (()->Unit)? = null
...
// When you want to invoke the listener
listener?.invoke()
```

Inside your Activity

```
mCircleShape.listener = {
    // Do something when you observed a call
}
```

Answer (score 70):

define a function like this:

```
  fun performWork(param1: String, myCallback: (result: String?) -> Unit) {
    // perform some network work

    // on network finished
    myCallback.invoke("result from network")
  }
```

use like this:

```
  performWork("http://..."){ result ->
  //use result
  }
```

Comment: You can call just `myCallback("result string")`

Comment: Is there a way to pass two variables at different times

Answer (score 41):

On CircleShape.kt.

```
private listener OnClickListenerInterface? = null
...
fun setOnClickListener(listener: OnClickListenerInterface) {
    this.listener = listener
}
```

On your Activity

```
mCircleShape.setOnClickListener(object: CircleShape.OnClickListenerInterface {
    override fun onClick() {
      // Do something here
    }
})
```

If you're gonna use lambda expression, you can use a Function Type. Here how it looks like
on CirclesShapt.kt

```
fun setOnClickListener(listener: () -> Unit){
   listener() // or you could use optional if the lister is nullable "listener?.invoke()"
}
```

So in activity looks like.

```
mCircleShape.setOnClickListener {
  // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Your second solutions doesn't demonstrate how the setOnClickListener in CirclesShapt.kt is suppose to call the listener.

Answer (score 9):

to use Kotlin callbacks , 
I use them in my api calls for success or failure
use

> create enum class for state

```
enum class APIState(val result: Boolean) {
SUCCESS(true),
FAILURE(false)}
```

> use call back in fun

```
 private fun fetchFeesList(studentID:String,call:(APIState)->Unit){
 ... do stuff here , and use call(APIState.SUCCESS) or call(APIState.FAILURE) }
```

> when calling function fetchFeesList , call it like

```
fetchFeesList(studentID){
        val res = it.result
        if(res){
            toast("success")
        }else {
            toast("failure")
        }
    }
```

> for toast("message") , use Anko Lib from GitHub : - https://github.com/Kotlin/anko

Answer (score 5):

I was desperately looking for a Kotlin solution similar to what Java interfaces offer until I bumped into the suggestions offered thereabove. Having tried all of them, I was unable to arrive at a working solution that would suit my scenario.

This led to my own implementation which worked perfectly according to my use case, and therefore thought I could share the same here, though it may not be the perfect way of doing it, apologies in advance.

The steps:

- **1. Define your interface:**

```
interface OnClickListenerInterface {
    fun onClick()
}
```

- **2. Inside the class that will trigger the "onClick" callback i.e. "CircleShape" for your case:**

Create a nullable variable.

```
var listener: OnClickListenerInterface? = null
```

Declare a function to initialise the variable above.

```
fun initOnClickInterface(listener: OnClickListenerInterface){
        this.listener = listener
    }
```

At the point where you want to trigger the "onClick" callback:

```
mCircleShape.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
      if (listener == null) return@OnClickListener
      listener?.onClick() // Trigger the call back
    })
```

- **3. Inside the activity where you want to receive the "onClick" callback:**

Make the activity implement the OnClickListenerInterface, then create an object of your CircleShape class.

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), OnClickListenerInterface {
    val mCircleShape = CircleShape()
    // ...other stuff
```

Inside the onCreate function of this activity, initialise your interface using the initOnClickInterface function we created in the CircleShape class.

```
mCircleShape.initOnClickListenerInterface(this)
```

Then finish by overriding the onClick method of our interface by adding the code below in the activity.

```
override fun onClick() {
        // Callback received successfully. Do your stuff here
    }
```

The above steps worked for me.

As I said, in case of any issues with my coding, I'm a learner too .

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a lambda expression? For example in your case:

```
mCircleShape.setOnClickListener( 
    { _ -> ToastUtils.showSuccessMessage(context,"pressed") }
)
```

Or if you want to make it more kotlin style:

```
mCircleShape.listener = ( 
    { _ -> ToastUtils.showSuccessMessage(context,"pressed") }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested. This worked.

```
// Define interface
interface MyCallback {
    fun success(param: String)
    fun fail(param: String)
}

fun functionHasCallback(param: Boolean, callback: MyCallback) {
    // do somthing
    if (ok) {
        callback.success("value")
    } else {
        callback.fail("value")
    }
}

// Call function
functionHasCallback(
    boolParam, 
    object: MyCallback {
        override fun success(param: String) {
            // Your code here
        }

        override fun fail(param: String) {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove this code:

```
mCircleShape.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
      if (listener == null) return@OnClickListener
      listener!!.onClick()
    })
```

Because listener is always null at first and your code just always returns.

`var listener: OnClickListenerInterface? = null` is already public (this is a default access level in Kotlin). So you can just set it in your activity, when needed. Use `listener?.onClick()` call to trigger it from your CircleShape.