# How can I access and use button of one fragment inside another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I've one fragment, `HomeFragment()`. In this fragment I've `TabLayout` with `ViewPager2`. In `viewPager2` there is another fragment called `ordersFragment()`. Is it possible that I can click on any button that is placed in `HomeFragment()` and display some text in ordersFragment()`?

Comment: HomeFragment hosting the TabLayout or a fragment inside the viewPager2?

Comment: Yes HomeFragment hosting the TabLayout

Comment: if HomeFragment hosting the tablayout and the button, it should also be able to access the ordersFragment object.

Comment: In HomeFragment (that is hosting) there is a filter icon on top, so want to show and hide search bar inside ordersFragment() on click of that filter icon that is placed in  HomeFragment()

Comment: How please guide me

Comment: It is easy to access activity button in fragment but I want to access Fragment button in another fragment

Comment: Are you able to  access the ordersFragment object from HomeFragment ? If so, create a function in ordersFragment to do the hide and show logic, and call the function from HomeFragment

Comment: No I think I'm not able to access object

Comment: calling a function of ordersFragment  is the easiest way to go, consider posting your HomeFragment to review your design

Comment: Can you give me some solution in term of answer so I understand your point.

Comment: post your HomeFragment  please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd really recommend using the modern approach, which is the [`ViewModels` component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). A view model is basically a class that holds your data and state, and the component enables each fragment in your activity to fetch the same view model instance, so they're all looking at the same thing

That way, one fragment can set a value for some data, while another fragment `observe`s it and gets notified whenever there's an update. Neither fragment needs to know about each other, they're just talking to the view model and observing the stuff they need to worry about. There's an example of this kind of thing [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

You *can* coordinate all this stuff yourself (e.g. by going through the parent `Activity` and making that talk to the other fragment) but you're adding a lot of work and boilerplate which `ViewModel`s take care of for you. And it helps you to separate your UI (displaying stuff, handling user interactions) from the business logic (doing something with that data, updating the app state). It's definitely good to know and makes communication around your app a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use callback implemented in one fragment and call that in another fragment.

if you are using kotlin check this..

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499891/how-i-can-use-callback-in-kotlin)
(i don't want to copy paste same code here)

Comment: But this callback is applied between fragment & activity. Can we apply the same callback method between two fragments?

Comment: yes can use in multiple fragments, but if the fragment is active only callback will work else it won't work.