# How can I return value from callback in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback

How can I send the result to the ViewModel in this case???

```
val callback: (OAuthToken?, Throwable?) -> Unit = { token, error ->
    if (error != null) {
        // TODO: error return to viewModel
    } else if (token != null) {
        // TODO: success return to viewModel
    }
}

fun signInWithABC() {
    abcApi.signIn(callback = callback)
}
```

I think signInWithABC should returns to the ViewModel, not from callback directly...
maybe like this..

```
fun signInWithABC(): Result<AuthData> {
    return abcApi.signIn(callback = callback)
}
```

But, I don't know how to do it..

Should I fix it like this? It doesn't look clean though.

```
fun signInWithABC() {
    abcApi.signIn(){ token, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            // TODO: error return to viewModel
        } else if (token != null) {
            // TODO: success return to viewModel
        }
    }
}
```

And I also tried it with this.. but it has return problem. lamda can't return the value for the function. But it can only return for the block..

```
fun signInWithABC(): Result<String> {
    abcApi.signIn(){ token, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            return Result.failure<Throwable>(error)
        } else if (token != null) {
            return Result.success(token)
        }
    }
    return Result.failure(throw IllegalAccessException())
}
```

Comment: set the value in mutablelivedata or use sealed class for getting the value from viewmodel in activity/fragment

Comment: By definition a function can't return from a callback because it happens asynchronous. You need to use some kind of observable solution, like for example livedata

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75017637/9585130

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to do callback to suspend conversion.
Here is a simple example of doing this:

```kotlin
suspend fun signInWithABC(): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation -> 
    abcApi.signIn(){ token, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            continuation.resume("Error")
        } else {
            continuation.resume(token) // Assuming token is a string
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for simple cases in Kotlin. Love it